# When passing value into the getKey method of DualHashBidiMap i am getting null. even though it exists...?

Tags: java

I am stuck... i have iterated through the below DualHashBidiMap and all the values are there. So this is what is happening. I have a file, lets say static.java which has a class:

```
public class Constant {
   public static final DualHashBidiMap<String, String> STATE_CODE_MAP = new DualHashBidiMap() {
       {
           put("Delaware","00000");
           put("Maryland","11111");
           put("New Jersey","22222");
           put("New York","33333");
           put("Pennsylvania","444444");
           put("Virginia","55555");
       }
}
```

I am trying to get the key for a value by using this:

```
public static String code2State(String code) {
    log.debug("State Code : " + code);
    String result = Constant.STATE_CODE_MAP.getKey(code);
    log.debug("State : " + result);
    return result;
}
//output
//State Code : 55555
//State : null
```

I am calling this method and getting a null in return. Am i missing something...?

(Java 1.7)

Comment: How do you call the method? (include that code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps associate a key with a value, where normally the first value is the key, and the second the value.
In your example, you map the state names (keys) to the state codes (values), and then try to request a key by its value.
To fix this, swap the arguments in the list initialization:

```
put("00000", "Delaware");
put("11111", "Maryland");
put("22222", "New Jersey");
put("33333", "New York");
put("444444", "Pennsylvania");
put("55555", "Virginia");
```